# How to run tests for a node app deployed on Cloud Run with Cloud Build

Tags: node.js, docker, containers, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-build

I have a nodejs  API running on Google cloud Run and am using Cloud Build for continuous Deployment.

I would need to run tests so that in case of errors found, cloud Build does not deploy the image to cloud Run. How can I implement this either in Dockerfile or using anyother way.

Comment: Can you provide more information?  how you current build process and logs?

Comment: The building process is all fine but would like to test the image in the pipeline. Let me use the solution below. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 solutions

- Either you start your API in background and run tests on it.
- Or, if you want to test the container, deploy the container on Cloud Run, in a staging instance and test it. If the tests are ok, continue and deploy the container on the correct service.

You can't run a container inside Cloud Build (Docker in Docker aren'r permitted. In fact, you can run the container, but the port forwarding is forbidden, so you can test your API with the container started!)

Comment: Thanks. To be clear for solution 1, hope you meant building the image and testing it locally. This is what have been doing.

However, I wished to test the image in the pipeline, since 'Docker in Docker aren't permitted', then will go for solution 2 by setting up a staging instance.
Cheers